# Cannot format micro SD Card in mac OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, sd-card

I tried everything but I cannot format it.

When opening the disk utilities I get 2 partitions, one which is greyed out. When trying to format the first one it says "couldn't unmount disk". When trying to erase the second one it says "couldn't modify partition map". With SD Formatter it says "not found any media" and if it does, it cannot erase it (don't remember the error).

Is there any other way to FORCE the formatting of the micro SD Card? I wonder if it's possible to erase it or it is just broken (even though it just stayed there for a while and did not fall or anything).

Thanks

P.S. The micro SD card is inside an adapter, but it's still a micro SD Card

Comment: You can always format the micro SD using another device, like a phone or so, then remove the new create data like folders.

Comment: I actually don't have any of those devices, I only have my mac and a raspberry pi where the SD should host the OS... so I cannot use that :-(. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Try to unmount the SD and format it with the disk manager.

Comment: If I unmount it (eject in mac), I cannot see it anymore in the disk utilities application :-(

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that the adapter is "Unlocked"
It is a physical slider on the side of the adapter. This same problem happened to me and all I had to do was slide the dial.